# How can I configure the Dark Reader Google Chrome extension so that the Filter+ mode is only activated for PDFs?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, google-chrome-extensions, themes, color-theme

How can I configure the [Dark Reader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-reader/eimadpbcbfnmbkopoojfekhnkhdbieeh?hl=en-US) Google Chrome extension so that the Filter+ mode is only activated for PDFs? For the other webpages I want to keep the dynamic mode.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently not possible to configure the [Dark Reader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-reader/eimadpbcbfnmbkopoojfekhnkhdbieeh?hl=en-US) Google Chrome extension so that the Filter+ mode is only activated for PDFs, so that other page still have the dynamic mode.